# Getting the Remote Name Address (not IP)

Tags: .net, asp.net

I wanted to show the users Name Address (see [www.ipchicken.com](http://www.ipchicken.com)), but the only thing I can find is the IP Address. I tried a reverse lookup, but didn't work either:

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(this.lblIp.Text);
string hostName = Dns.GetHostByAddress(ip).HostName;
this.lblHost.Text = hostName;
```

But HostName is the same as the IP address.

Who know's what I need to do?

Thanks.
Gab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit of my previous answer. 
Try (in vb.net):

```
    Dim sTmp As String
    Dim ip As IPHostEntry

    sTmp = MaskedTextBox1.Text
    Dim ipAddr As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(sTmp)
    ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddr)
    MaskedTextBox2.Text = ip.HostName
```

Dns.resolve appears to be obsolete in later versions of .Net. As stated here before I believe the issue is caused by your IP address not having a fixed name or by it having multiple names. The example above works with Google addresses, but not with an address we use that has a couple of names associated with it.

Answer (score 2):

You need the Dns.Resolve() method from System.Net

See this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DougBell/NSLookUpDB00112052005013753AM/NSLookUpDB001.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Stupid me... The code is posted was 100% valid and working... But 10 lines lower I replaced the this.lblHost.Text with another value, which happened to be the ip address.

Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that reverse lookup won't allways give the same address as the one used in forward DNS lookup.

For example for google.com I get ip 64.233.167.99
but reverse dns lookup for that IP returns py-in-f99.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Not all IP addresses need to have hostnames. I think that's what is happening in your case. Try it ouy with more well-known IP/hostname pairs eg:

> Name: google.com Address: 72.14.207.99
>
> Name: google.com Address:
>   64.233.187.99
>
> Name: google.com Address:
>   64.233.167.99

...I might just be wrong

Answer (score 0):

A lot of users have the same shared IP address, so you will not be able to find their hostnames. And a lot of users won't necessarily have DNS records in public DNS for the IPs they are coming from as well.